# Mnesia: how to use indexed operations correctly when selecting rows based on criteria involving multiple, indexed columns

Tags: erlang, mnesia

#### Problem:

How to select records efficiently from a table where the select is based on criteria involving two indexed columns.

#### Example

I have a record,

```
#rec{key, value, type, last_update, other_stuff}
```

- I have indexes on key (default), type and last_update columns
- type is typically an atom or string
- last_update is an integer (unix-style milliseconds since 1970)

I want, for example all records whose type = Type and have been updated since a specific time-stamp.

I do the following (wrapped in a non-dirty transaction)

```
lookup_by_type(Type, Since) ->
    MatchHead = #rec{type=Type, last_update = '$1', _= '_'},
    Guard = {'>', '$1', Since},
    Result = '$_',
    case mnesia:select(rec,[{MatchHead, [Guard],[Result]}]) of
    []    -> {error, not_found};
    Rslts -> {ok, Rslts}
    end.
```

#### Question

- Is the lookup_by_type function even using the underlying indexes?
- Is there a better way to utilize indexes in this case
- Is there an entirely different approach I should be taking?

Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way, which will probably help you, is to look at QLC queries. These are more SQL/declarative and they will utilize indexes if possible by themselves IIRC.

But the main problem is that indexes in mnesia are hashes and thus do not support range queries. Thus you can only efficiently index on the `type` field currently and not on the `last_update` field.

One way around that is to make the table `ordered_set` and then shove the `last_update` to be the primary key. The `key` parameter can then be indexed if you need fast access to it. One storage possibility is something like: `{{last_update, key}, key, type, ...}`. Thus you can quickly answer queries because `last_update` is orderable.

Another way around it is to store last-update separately. Keep a table `{last_update, key}` which is an ordered set and use that to limit the amount of things to scan on the larger table in a query.

Remember that mnesia is best used as a small in-memory database. Thus scans are not necessarily a problem due to them being in-memory and thus pretty fast. Its main power though is the ability to do key/value lookups in a dirty way on data for quick query.

Comment: If I make the primary key {last_update, key} will read functions on they primary key of {0,SomeKey} or {12434,_} be efficient as compared to having the ordered_set plus second key column as you suggested?

Comment: I made the change to use {LastUpdate,Key} as the primary key and have seen an order of magnitude improvement in reading large groups of keys. Thanks